# Could PIE y / Gothic ji be related to Holtzmann's y / jj?

Tags: germanic-languages

Could PIE *kór**y**os / Gothic har**ji**s be related to Holtzmann's y / jj?
Taking into account Proto-Germanic j / Gothic i *nat**j**ą / nat**i** ?